# Svn Server Setup (OS X)

Tags: svn, repository

My machine is running on OS X Yosemite (10.10)
All I wanted to do is setup a SVN project so that my colleagues can use my machine as SVN server for version control.

I know OS X has inbuilt capability if you have Xcode installed. So, I have SVN working already. Checked 'svn --version' in terminal and it works!

Now, I do not know how to setup a SVN project and create users through Terminal. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't do this. Set up a standalone server (or find a hosting provider). What happens to your colleagues when your computer goes offline? Or the hard drive crashes?

Answer (score 0):

Having SVN-**client** does not mean automagically, that you have SVN-server tools

You have to have at least `svnserve` in order to get `svn://`-served repository running

Comment: Possible to help me with some process to have SVN Server up & running on my machine (OS X)?

Comment: @NagarajChandran - check `svnserve --version` for start

Comment: svnserve, version 1.6.5 (r38866)

Comment: @NagarajChandran - http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html

Answer (score 0):

These are the detailed steps

```
# run server
#
svnserve -d -r /your_path/repos

# create repo
#
cd /your_path/repos
svnadmin create test1 --fs-type fsfs


#
# set anonymous access
#

cd repos/test1/conf
vi svnserve.conf

# allow write
anon-access = write

# NO NEED TO RESTART DAEMON !



# use client
svn ls svn://YourHostName/test1

# See "System Preferences / Sharing" to get YourHostName
```